# Url Problem with translation

Tags: i18n-l10n

I have a site in Italian and i want to translated it into various languages​​. My problem is that I put around the net number of links to my site and now if I translate it all the urls will be changed (it will be added /it or / en ... etc.) and not recognized by the various links I've posted.
How can 'solve the matter in your opinion?
Thanks!

Comment: There will not be any change in arguments even drupal adds /en /es to paths

Comment: So the links still works? Thank you Nikhil!

Comment: It looks like the problem persist

Comment: Which are the modules you installed ? Edit your question with installed modules list.

Comment: For now I'm just using the drupal core locale and content translations modules.

Comment: Try print `base_url` and `arg(1)` in `page.tpl` and check whether any change in url structure.

Comment: Does that solved your problem ?